# Background image is not working in my stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to implement a mobile menu loading URL image in CSS. But the image is not showing. I inspected it using the browser dev tool, also it's not loading. Check the full code below.
I tried background: url(/source/close.png); and  background-image: url(/source/close.png);
but no any result. I need to fix this.

```
.toggle.active {
    background-image: url(/source/close.png);
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue is that you need to put a dot before slash and wrap it in `''` or `""` . i mean:

```
.toggle.active {
    background-image: url("./source/close.png");
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: "you need to put a dot before slash" — That's a different URL pointing to a different place. What makes you think that is the correct URL and that the original URL is wrong?

Comment: "and wrap it in `''` or `""`" — No. There is absolutely no need for quotes here.

Comment: Note that W3Schools is often terrible. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Quentin Why is W3Schools terrible, I mean its for beginners but that doesn't makes it terrible.

Comment: It has plenty of errors and pretty much every tutorial that could teach someone how to write code with security holes in it does.

Comment: @Quentin Oh i didn't know this but thanks for noting this!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct file path and file extension?
Because, sometimes you accidentally enter the wrong path or wrong file suffix.

Comment: I use (./) to get the path because it opens the file path automatically

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had problems with images saved in png file format, so i tried to convert the image file type to jpg and it worked for me. (I am very new to Stack, please pardon me for doing something wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path. For debugging purpose you can open developer tools and check for this particular resource, what is the resource path is forming and response http code.